# What makes that difference By putting extra zero on left hand side

Tags: java

Just started to learn programming could u explain whats difference between them

```
public class tst {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int mk=1200;
        System.out.println(mk);
    }

}

public class tst {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int mk=01200;
        System.out.println(mk);
    }
}
```

First one gave result `1200` while second one `640`.

Answer (score 4):

A leading 0 makes the compiler parse the number as an octal number (radix 8). The decimal value of 01200 octal is 640.

Comment: is that because System.out.println??As according to me it converts the value into  String??

Comment: @mayankkumar println converts an integer to a String of its decimal representation.

Answer (score 2):

A leading zero implies an *octal literal*; so 01200 is base 8 which, in decimal, is 640.

Essentially this is paying homage to older times where octal literals were much more common. These days though it's more likely to be a distraction and cause for confusion. There are movements to propose the more deliberate `0o` notation for an octal literal.